# Как сделать такую страницу регистрации?

Tags: html, css, регистрация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать приблизительно вот такую вот страницу для регистрации с полями в таком порядке и расположении в приблизительных размерах?

Не получается выстроить так же в ряд поля для ввода и добавить слоты для изображений в таком порядке..

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Лично я  сделал бы гридах сделал.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. С чем из изображённого возникают затруднения?

Comment: А еще можно пойти на фриланс биржу, там отдать пару десятков золотых и вам все сделают.

Comment: Конкретно вот эта страница, не получается распределить в ширину поля для ввода информации и добавить слоты для изображений..

Comment: @Александр Вас просят приложить мини пример с вашей проблемой. По изображению или комментариям никто не даст вам точный ответ.

Comment: @MaxWatson Я конкретно про поля для ввода спрашиваю, их расположение. Как сделать так, что б они шли столбиками, а потом снизу все остальное вряд было, как на фото?

Comment: @Александр А я вам еще раз конкретно повторяю. Создайте мини пример в котором отображается ваша проблема и добавьте его в свой вопрос.

Comment: @Александр: это явно bootstrap. "Курите" мануал по нему.

Comment: @UModeL Не так уж и явно... Вполне себе могут быть чистые наколенные `grid`, `flex`, `inline`, да даже `table` ))

Comment: @Александр а там,, где вы это заскриншотили, оно так и есть картинкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы все заверстала флексами. Разметка и размеры на картинке.

Розовые колонки это 2/5 и 3/5 от ширины (40% и 60%), отступ между колонками сделать через column-gap.
Колонка "длительность" фиксированного размера, колонка с днями работы резиновая и тянется на всю ширину. В ней сделать обертки, у которых одинаковый класс, в котором прописать высоту и отступы (а уже внутри label, у которых обводочка).

В добавить фото у вас блоки занимают 1/6 пространства, то есть, 16,67%. Или width: calc(16.67% - паддинги).

В общем, задай сетку как на картинке, задай элементам отступы и размеры, а сами элементы отрисуй отдельно внутри.

Ну и приложи разметку что получается, в следующий раз. Чтобы твой пример поправить быстренько.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]